# Libreoffice missing menus in XFCE4

Tags: xfce, gtk, libreoffice

I have Linux Mint 17.2 64 bit (14.04 base) originally a KDE install. I installed XFCE4 from repos (4.10.1) and other desktops recently, but Libreoffice (4.4.3.2 40m0(Build:2) is not showing the Menus at the top of the screen after installing libreoffice-gtk. Checking an existing working install this package is installed (and not using gtk3).

I am baffled what else I need to do to enable the menus. I have tried a clean profile, even a new user with no change in the problem. All I can think of at the moment is I am missing a package. Screenshot below

[image: Missing menus in libreoffice]

Comment: What happens if you press Alt or Alt+F etc (when Libreoffice window is open)?

Comment: Nothing happens when I press Alt or Alt+F or F10